# Numerical algorithms for finding the period of solution to ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the autonomous ode

$$ \dot{x}(t) = f(x(t)) $$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and its initial condition $x(0) = x_0$. Let's assume it is known that the solution of this ode is periodic but the period is unknown.

Are there any standard numerical algorithms to find the period of the solution efficiently? If yes, where can I read about them and the underlying problem?

Comment: Since this ODE is autonomous,  it reaches the periodic boundary when $x(t) = x_0$, repeating the initial condition.  That said I think you need a *system* of ODEs to get nonconstant periodic solutions, though I might be misremembering an exercise similar to that.

Comment: @hardmath: It *is* a system, since $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.